# How to get The Selected Year and Month from drop down list to controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

How to get the Selected Year and month from the drop down list from view to controller. When i tried its giving error as There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key "Yearitems". As i'm a new to Asp.net mvc so any help will be Appriciated. Thanks in Advance.

This is My View

```
<h3>Search by PhoneNumber:@Html.TextBox("SearchString",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)  </h3>


    <p><h3>Year:@Html.DropDownList("Yearitems",    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectList as SelectList, "Select Year")</h3>

    <h3>Month:@Html.DropDownList("MonthItems",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectMonthList as SelectList,"Select Month")</h3></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Yearitems").change(function () {

            //alert($("#Yearitems>option:selected").attr("Value"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetMonths","AirtelManagement")',
                data: { YearId: $("#Yearitems>option:selected").attr("Value") },
                datatype: "Json",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#MonthItems").html("");
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        $("#MonthItems").append(new Option(item.MonthName, item.MonthSelectedId));
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Select Year");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

}
```

This is My controller.

```
     public ActionResult ViewDataOfDatabase(string sortorder, string currentFilter,  string searchString, int? page,string SelecetedYear,string SelectedMonth)
     {

         AirtelManagementModel _Airtelmodel = new AirtelManagementModel();
         IEnumerable<clsYearOfDate> SelectList = GetYears();
         //IEnumerable<MonthListClass> SelectMonthList = GetMonths(YearId);
         IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Yearitems = (from v in SelectList
                                             select new SelectListItem()
                                             {
                                                 Value = v.YearSelectedId.ToString(),
                                                 Text = v.YearOfDate.ToString(),


                                             });
         ViewBag.SelectList = Yearitems;

         //IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthItems = (from m in SelectMonthList
         //                                          select new SelectListItem()
         //                                          {
         //                                              Value = m.MonthSelectedId.ToString(),
         //                                              Text = m.MonthName,


         //                                          });
         //ViewBag.SelectMonthList = MonthItems;
         IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthItems = Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>();
         ViewBag.SelectMonthList = MonthItems;
        List<AirtelManagementModel> list = ViewDetails();
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortorder;

        ViewBag.PhoneSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortorder) ? "Phone_desc" : "";
        if (searchString != null )
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            searchString = currentFilter;
        }
        //if(searchString!=null)
        //{
        ViewBag.SelectList = SelecetedYear;
        ViewBag.SelectMonthList = SelectedMonth;
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
            var airteldetails = from _model in list
                                select _model;
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                airteldetails=airteldetails.Where(A=>A.AirtelNumber.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToString()));

            }

            //airteldetails=airteldetails.OrderByDescending(A=>A.AirtelNumber);
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1); 
            //return View(airteldetails.ToList());
            return View(airteldetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        //}
        //if (list.Count > 0)
        //{
        //    var airteldetails = from _model in list
        //                        select _model;
        //    return View(airteldetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "No Data found in Database");
        //    return RedirectToAction("ImportExcelFile", "AirtelManagement");
        //}
    }
```

Comment: can you post your controller action method?

Comment: Check it.. I've added now.

Comment: But Yearitems and MonthItems variables already present in the controller action @Gary Schreiner

Comment: The controller action has SelectedMonth and SelectedYear as an input parameter, not YearItems and MonthItems as defined in the DropDownList (SELECT)'s name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your Select/DDL needs to be the same as the parameter on your controller action method, ie `public ActionResult ViewDataOfDatabase(...,String YearItems, String MonthItems)`or change the name in your `@Html.DropDownList("name"...` to `SelectedMonth` and `SelectedYear` to match that of the DDL

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from `FormCollection`:

```
public ActionResult ViewDataOfDatabase(FormCollection form)
{

    string Month = form["MonthItems"].ToString();
 .............................
..............................

}
```

Comment: While this is a possibility, I find that it opens you up for somebody editing the html and submitting the form, forcing you to add more null checking and parameter checking in the code. If you explicitly define the strongly typed input parameters, then the entire action will error out and throw a 500 before even moving into the code. Just makes it a little cleaner, adds validation at the beginning, and IMHO is more secure.

Comment: yes @GarySchreiner very first option preffered is strongly type view with Model object but in Op scenario the way Op is doing its much better to use FormCollection